# How to remove elements from array using a filter object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to filter an array given a filter object

```
function remove (array, filter) {
  // magic
}
```

`filter` is an object of variable size with any number of key/value

It should act as follows

```
const products = [
  { size: 'S', color: 'blue' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'S', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'green' },
]

// With a filter of keys/value it filters for the existing key/values
const filteredProducts1 = remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red' })

console.log(filteredProducts1)
/*
[
  { size: 'S', color: 'blue' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'green' },
]
*/

// With less key/value than the object array, it filters for the existing key/value
const filteredProducts2 = remove(products, { size: 'S' })

console.log(filteredProducts2)
/*
[
  { size: 'L', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'green' },
]
*/

// With more keys/values than the object array it discard the non-existing key/value
const filteredProducts1 = remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red', type: 'dress' })

console.log(filteredProducts1)
/*
[
  { size: 'S', color: 'blue' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'green' },
]
*/
```

My issue is in building a dynamic condition from the filter object

I'm trying to convert

```
{ key1: value1, key2: value2, ... , keyN: valueN }
```

into

```
condition 1 && condition2 && ... & conditionN
```

Comment: hint: array.every

Comment: my bad some is better suited in this case since you are filtering out not satisfying

Comment: btw how you get M in the results when it is not in input

Comment: It’s a typo. I corrected the original post

Comment: ok i think many figured it out already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `some` to return true if at least one of the conditions is exists and not equal to filter.
you can even use `x[k]` instead of `x.hasOwnProperty(k)` if it is guaranteed that there will be keys which point to values with falsy values (`undefined`,`null`,`0`..,`''`).
Also MDN recommends [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) instead of `Object.hasOwnProperty` if your environment (browser/Node) supports it.

```js
function remove (array, filter) {
  return array.filter((x) => Object.entries(filter).some(([k,v]) => x.hasOwnProperty(k) && x[k] !== v))
}

const products = [
  { size: 'S', color: 'blue' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'S', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'green' },
]

console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red' }))
console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S' }))
console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red', type: 'dress' }))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**edit**
to fix the problem

> remove(products, { type: 'dress' }) removes everything while it shouldn't

now I'm filtering out the fields from the filter entries that are existing in the object to check and returning the whole array if the filter entries is empty

```js
function remove (array, filter) {
  return array.filter((x,i) => {
    const entries =  Object.entries(filter).filter(([k,_]) => x.hasOwnProperty(k))
    if (entries.length === 0) return array
    return entries.some(([k,v]) => x[k] !== v)
  })
}

const products = [
  { size: 'S', color: 'blue' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'S', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'green' },
]

console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red' }))
console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S' }))
console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red', type: 'dress' }))
console.log(remove(products, { type: 'dress' }))
console.log(remove(products, {}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `remove(products, { type: 'dress' })` removes everything while it shouldn't

Comment: @eakl can you check again. im not sure if i missed any other edge cases

Comment: It seems to work fine. even with value being null or undefined

Comment: @eakl i hope now you got some idea where to change when things don't work

Answer (score 0):

You can determine whether any key-value pair in the filter is present in each object in the array:

```js
function remove(array, filter) {
  return array.filter((obj) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filter)) {
      if (obj[key] === value) return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
}

const products = [
  { size: "M", color: "blue" },
  { size: "S", color: "blue" },
  { size: "L", color: "red" },
  { size: "S", color: "red" },
  { size: "L", color: "green" },
];

console.log(remove(products, { size: "S", color: "red" }));
// [ { size: "M", color: "blue" }, { size: "L", color: "green" } ]

console.log(remove(products, { size: "S" }));
// [ { size: "M", color: "blue" }, { size: "L", color: "red" }, { size: "L", color: "green" } ]

console.log(remove(products, { size: "S", color: "red", type: "dress" }));
// [ { size: "M", color: "blue" }, { size: "L", color: "green" } ]
```

Comment: `remove(products, { size: "S", color: "red" })` should remove `size = S AND color = blue`. Your function removes any condition that is met. not when all conditions are met/

Answer (score 0):

How about this, variable filters will return array of boolean of matching filter [true, false, true] etc. Then just return back array item if included false in filters variable

```
const products = [
    { id: 1, size: 'S', color: 'blue', type: 'dress' },
    { id: 2, size: 'L', color: 'red', type: 'dress' },
    { id: 3, size: 'S', color: 'red', type: 'dress' },
    { id: 4, size: 'L', color: 'green', type: 'shirt' },
  ]

const filter1 = { size: 'S', color: 'red' }

const filter2 = { size: 'S' }

const filter3 = { size: 'S', color: 'red', type: 'dress' }

const remove = (products, filter) => {
    return products.filter(product => {
        const filters = Object.keys(filter).map(prop => {
            return filter[prop] === product[prop]
        })
        return filters.includes(false)
    })
}

const result1 = remove(products, filter1)
const result2 = remove(products, filter2)
const result3 = remove(products, filter3)

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)
```

Comment: In `remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red', type: 'dress' })` `type = dress` should be disregarded as the key doesn't exist. But size and color should work. In your code, `type = dress` changes the previous behavior from size and color. `remove(products, { type: 'dress' })` should not filter anything

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right on track, the key to solve your problem is to proper implement a function that can decide if an item should be removed or kept based on the key-values passed, and that should be able to handle dynamically your requirements.

Here is one suggestion for it:

```js
const shouldkeep = kvs => obj => {
  for (const k in kvs)
    if (k in obj && obj[k] !== kvs[k]) 
      return true
  return false
}
const remove = (array, filter) => array.filter(shouldkeep(filter))

const products = [
  { size: 'S', color: 'blue' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'S', color: 'red' },
  { size: 'L', color: 'green' },
] 

console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red' }))
console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S' }))
console.log(remove(products, { size: 'S', color: 'red', type: 'dress' }))
```

A few notes about this implementation:

- the idea of the function `shouldkeep` is that it iterates over the keys of your filter object, and only returns true (which means "keep") if it passes through all the keys without fully matching values
- this syntax `shouldkeep = kvs => obj =>` might seem weird, but it is actually very useful. It is called *currying*, and means you can apply one argument to the function and get back a function that expects the next argument. With this, you can do something like `products, {size: 'S'})` and it returns a function that you can use as a parameter to `filter`. Neat!

Comment: remove(products, { type: 'dress' }) removes everything while it shouldn't